# Is there a way to queue a task (i.e. HTTP request) to be executed once a net connection is available?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, xamarin.ios

Is there a way to queue some executable task (i.e. HTTP request) to be executed once a network connection is available, given that the app is suspended by the time network connectivity is re-established?

A typical scenario would be:

A user, on a train, opens an app. They modify some state within the app which has then got to be transmitted to some server. The user then closes/suspends the app. Unfortunately during the time the app was active the iphone had no signal and only regained that signal at the next train station. At this point, of re-established connection, I would like to have some task be awakened so that it can attempt to perform the transmission of modified state to the server.

Is this possible? I would also be happy if the task could only be implemented as some kind of cron / scheduled task where the task could check for connectivity and attempt a transmission periodically.

Answer (score 3):

The simple answer is no, the current iOS architecture doesn't provide what you want. You can't explicitly schedule arbitrary operations to occur at defined times when your applications not running.

But if you wanted to consider 'creative' solutions, I'd think along these lines:

iCloud - you might just get exactly the behavior you're describing if you can work within the constraints of this very specific platform. I'm not sure how iCloud queues network operations while offline and whether or not synchronization occurs only during your runtime.

Location Notifications - In your application, create a network operation queue however you wish as long as it's persistent. Add events to it while you're running offline. Next, register your application for 'significant change' location events. You'll often (sorry; can't say precisely how often) get these when the device goes off and then comes back on another network/cell tower. These notifications can trigger your application into an active background state, where you could then attempt to fire off your persisted network operation queue.

Comment: If creative is all I have then creative I will be!

Answer (score 1):

Not without the user restarting the app, no. Sorry :( You're not allowed a background task like that on an iPhone.

The best you can do is to set a flag when the app is closed so that the next time it start up it knows to perform your request.